# play framework spring JPA Exception : org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework

i use  `Play Framework + Spring + JPA` in my App.

when I use

```
public class Entity{
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private String comm;
}
public class Respository{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    public Entity find(Long id){
         return em.find(Entity.class,id);
    }
}
public class MyService{
    @Resource
    Repository rep;
    public Entity find(Long id){
         return rep.find(id);
    }
}
@Controller
public class App extends Controller{
    @Resource
    private MyService service;
    public Result index(){
        Entity e = service.find(1L);
        return ok("");
    }
}
```

i get an error,This is my error:org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at models.UserInfo_$$_jvstbad_0.getId(UserInfo_$$_jvstbad_0.java)
    at controllers.UserApplication.afterQQLogin(UserApplication.java:149)**
```

**could not initialize proxy - no Session**

In the play, how to solve this problem

Comment: Which line of code produces this error? Please show us the stacktrace.

Comment: `public class MyService{
    @Resource
    Repository rep;
    public Entity find(Long id){
         return rep.find(id);
    }
}`